# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to build string by using %@ for an int

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access

For the use within Core Data I tried to build a `NSPredicate` object. `minLength` and `maxLength` are of type`int`:

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length >= %@ AND length <= %@",
                          minLength, maxLength];
```

The program crashes here with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. This is not the case if I use `%d` instead of `%@`:

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length >= %d AND length <= %d",
                          minLength, maxLength];
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`%@` is the [format specifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1) for objects. An `int` is not an object. The format specifier for signed integers is `%d` or `%i`.

Comment: If you for some reason need to treat them as objects, you can look into NSNumber.

Comment: Fantastic. This just helped me figure out an issue I've been having for hours.

Answer (score 5):

In format for int, you shouldn't use `%@`, but `%i`. `%@` is for objects`.